# Ionic - Email/Password required

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have authentication for my login when wrong email format, email or password, it will show a pop up error. However if nothing is type in both email and password, it will stuck at loading page. Anybody has a solution?

login.html

```
<ion-view title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true" hide-back-button="true" id="page6">    
<ion-content padding="true" style="background: url(img/fOM24l77SrSIyzBwqvMz_login.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding">

<div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 82px;"></div>
<h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;" align="center">Login with your NYP SIT account</h4>

    <form name="loginForm" class="list " id="login-form1">
            <ion-list class=" " id="login-list2">

                <div class="app-icon"></div>

                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label" style="color: #9F9F9F;">Email</span>
                    <input ng-model="user.email" style="color: white;" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label" style="color: #9F9F9F;" >Password</span>
                    <input ng-model="user.password" style="color: white;" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                </label>

            </ion-list>

            <div style="height: 40px;" class="spacer"></div>
            <button ng-click="loginEmail(loginForm,user)" class=" button button-assertive  button-block  icon-left ion-ios-email-outline "  id="signup-button3">LOGIN WITH EMAIL</button>
        </form>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, sharedUtils, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $rootScope.extras = false;  // For hiding the side bar and nav icon

    // When the user logs out and reaches login page,
// we clear all the history and cache to prevent back link
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(ev) {
  if(ev.targetScope !== $scope){
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  }
});


//Check if user already logged in
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {

//Removes back link to login page
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      historyRoot: true
    });
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);  // Sets up the sideMenu dragable
    $rootScope.extras = true;
    sharedUtils.hideLoading();
    $state.go('tabs.home', {}, {location: "replace"});

  }
});


$scope.loginEmail = function(formName,cred) {


  if(formName.$valid) {  // Check if the form data is valid or not

      sharedUtils.showLoading(); //starts the loading popup

      //Email Login via Firebase
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(cred.email,cred.password).then(function(result) {

            // You dont need to save the users session in your local session or cookies. Firebase handles it.

    // You only need to :
            // 1. clear the login page history from the history stack so that you cant come back
            // 2. Set rootScope.extra;
            // 3. Turn off the loading
            // 4. Got to menu page


          $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            historyRoot: true   //1
          });
          $rootScope.extras = true;  //2
          sharedUtils.hideLoading();  //3
          $state.go('tabs.home', {}, {location: "replace"}); //4

        },
        function(error) {
          sharedUtils.hideLoading();
          sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!","Authentication Error");
        }
    );

  }else{
    sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!","Enter in email format");
  }



};
```

})

Answer (score 3):

i think its better to check if the field is empty or not if fields are empty then you can show an error message

```
$scope.loginEmail = function(formName, cred) {

    if (formName && cred) { //checking for null
        if (formName.$valid) { // Check if the form data is valid or not

            sharedUtils.showLoading(); //starts the loading popup

            //Email Login via Firebase
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(cred.email, cred.password).then(function(result) {

                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        historyRoot: true //1
                    });
                    $rootScope.extras = true; //2
                    sharedUtils.hideLoading(); //3
                    $state.go('tabs.home', {}, {
                        location: "replace"
                    }); //4

                },
                function(error) {
                    sharedUtils.hideLoading();
                    sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!", "Authentication Error");
                }
            );

        } else {
            sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!", "Enter in email format");
        }
    } else {
        sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!", "Fields cannot be empty");
    }


};
```